# Change order/default item of firefox devtools

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

is there a way to put my custom contextMenu to the first place, or change the default item?

I don't want to open the devtools and then having to click on my extension

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your own context menu item first in the list. That is not possible. See this feature request which was rejected: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325758